# If an Arduino Mega only has 8 kb of SRAM, how am I able to use 14 kb without bugs?

Tags: arduino

**SOLVED apologies for wasting peoples' time, the comment on compiling with verbose made me realize I'm only using 91% available, I had an extra zero in one of my calculations!**

I've been working on an Arduino sketch for a number of years, slowly adding more variable declarations. Recently I upped the size of an array of longs from 24*70 to 24*100 and that seemed to cause unexplainable errors. (I have many other arrays but this is the biggest.)

I decided to count how many bytes approximately I am declaring in my sketch and just by counting the bigger array structures I came up with an approximate number of at least 14,000 bytes (taking into account longs are 4 bytes etc).

How is this possible? Where are the other 6000 bytes being stored? I should add that I've been using it like this for a number of years, it was only the upping of the bytes used from 14 kb to approximately 17 kb that caused the bugs.

Comment: I've requested a Moderator to move this to the arduino stackexchange ;)

Comment: 24*70*4 is 6270, so within 8k. Double check your totals.

Comment: The 24*70*4 array is only the largest of many arrays, I have a lot more making up the total of 14k

Comment: If you go back to a functioning version, and compile with verbose on, it will tell you how much RAM has been allocated. That could be a start to see what is really used.

Comment: thanks @dda that helped me solve the issue! j